# how does foreach loop work php?

Tags: php, foreach

for example:

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach($numbers as $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

what does `as` do, I assume it's a keyword because it is highlighted as one in my text editor. I checked the keyword list at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php and the `as` keyword was present. It linked to the `foreach` construct page, and from what I could tell didn't describe what the `as` keyword did. Does this `as` keyword have other uses or is it just used in the `foreach` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` is just part of the `foreach` syntax, it's used to specify the variables that are assigned during the iteration. I don't think it's used in any other context in PHP.

Comment: **+1** Barmar. You described it first.

Comment: Thanx, as Shankar Damodaran mentioned you described it first

Answer (score 2):

It's used to iterate over [Iterators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), e.g. arrays. It reads:

> foreach value in $numbers, assign the value to $value.

You can also do:

```
foreach ($numbers as $index => $value) {

}
```

Which reads:

> foreach value in $numbers, assign the index/key to $index and the value to $value.

To demonstrate the full syntax, lets say we have the following:

```
$array = array(
  0 => 'hello',
  1 => 'world')
);
```

For the first iteration of our foreach loop, `$index` would be `0` and `$value` would be 'hello'. For the second iteration of our foreach loop, `$index` would be `1`, and `$value` would be 'world'.

Foreach loops are very common. You may have seen them as for..in loops in other languages.

For the `as` keyword, you're saying:

> for each value in $numbers AS $value

It's a bit awkward, I know. As far as I know, the `as` keyword is only used with foreach loops.

Comment: *+1* for putting it in detail mate.